# using selector to enable/disable input text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thank "Abhishek Jain", "rps", "adeneo" for your code.
this help me to resolved it.

I have problem with below code:

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="addtable" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="4%"><b>Date</b></th>
    <th width="4%"><b>Cut Number</b></th>
    <th width="4%"><b>Content</b></th>
    <th width="4%"><b>Others</b></th>
    <th width="5%"><b>Customer name</b></th>
    <th width="4%"><b>Customer code</b></th>
    <th width="5%"><b>Address</b></th>
    <th width="5%"><b>Owe amount</b></th>
    <th width="4%"><b>Executive</b></th>
    <th width="6%"><b>Obtain Amount</b></th>
    <th width="9%"><b>Obtain Room</b></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="addrow">
    <td><input name="date[]" id="mask_dm1" type="text" size="1" value=""></td>
    <td><input name="cutno[]" type="text" size="6" ></td>
    <td>
        <select name="cutcontent[]" id="selector">
            <option value="0">Please select</option>
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="2">Value 2</option>
            <option value="3">Value 3</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input name="cutother[]" type="text" size="4"  id="cutother" disabled /></td>
    <td><input name="cusname[]" type="text" size="4" ></td>
    <td><input name="cuscode[]" type="text" size="2" ></td>
    <td><input name="cusaddress[]" type="text" size="4" ></td>
    <td><input name="owe[]" type="text" size="2"  id="cutowe" disabled /></td>
    <td><input name="executive[]" type="text" size="1"  /></td>
    <td><input name="obtainamount[]" type="text" size="2"  id="obtainamount" disabled /></td>
    <td><input name="obtainroom[]" type="text" size="2"  id="obtainroom" disabled /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clonedRow = '   <td><input name="date[]" id="mask_dm1" type="text" size="1" value=""></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="cutno[]" type="text" size="6" ></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td>';
    clonedRow += '          <select name="cutcontent[]" id="selector">';
    clonedRow += '              <option value="0">Please select</option>';
    clonedRow += '              <option value="1">Value 1</option>';
    clonedRow += '              <option value="2">Value 2</option>';
    clonedRow += '              <option value="3">Value 3</option>';
    clonedRow += '              <option value="other">Other</option>';
    clonedRow += '          </select>';
    clonedRow += '      </td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="cutother[]" type="text" size="4"  id="cutother" disabled /></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="cusname[]" type="text" size="4" ></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="cuscode[]" type="text" size="2" ></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="cusaddress[]" type="text" size="4" ></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="owe[]" type="text" size="2"  id="cutowe" disabled /></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="executive[]" type="text" size="1"  /></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="obtainamount[]" type="text" size="2"  id="obtainamount" disabled /></td>';
    clonedRow += '      <td><input name="obtainroom[]" type="text" size="2"  id="obtainroom" disabled /></td>';
    var appendRow = '<tr id="addrow">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';
    $('#btnAddMore').click(function () {
        $('#addtable tr:last').after(appendRow);
        $('select#selector').change(function () {
            var theVal = $(this).val();
            switch (theVal) {
                case '1':
                    $('input#cutowe').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('input#obtainamount').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('input#obtainroom').removeAttr('disabled');
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $('input#cutother').removeAttr('disabled');
                    break;
                default:
                    $('input#cutowe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('input#obtainamount').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('input#obtainroom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('input#cutother').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

    $('select#selector').change(function () {
        var theVal = $(this).val();
        switch (theVal) {
            case '1':
                $('input#cutowe').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('input#obtainamount').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('input#obtainroom').removeAttr('disabled');
                break;
            case '2':
                $('input#cutother').removeAttr('disabled');
                break;
            default:
                $('input#cutowe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('input#obtainamount').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('input#obtainroom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('input#cutother').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

When I press "Add more row" button, the selector named "Content" at row#2 has effect on the all input.
how to resolve it?
see example http://jsfiddle.net/N2jyy/6/

Comment: You appear to have lots and lots of duplicate `id` attributes. This will render your page invalid, and make DOM traversal much harder.

Comment: yes, i known, but how to appear different `id`?

Comment: Yes, you should not use ID's in templated HTML, but why not put the template inside a `<script id="template" type="text/template">` block in the page instead and reference that. Much more flexible than hand-coding HTML.

Comment: As you are using a template, a simple text replace can convert your id into something numbered or otherwise unique.

Comment: Chekc this example of mine where i create ten unique div's. I can access each div based on their id then. http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/GrNhL/

Comment: Hitech Magic, as you mean, I should generate this template by dynamic code? then I can specify my `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the duplicate ID's to classes, and use a delegated event handler to handle the change event on the select elements.

What you need to make each select only change the elements withing the same row is context, you'd do that like so:

```
$('#btnAddMore').on('click', function () {
    $('#addtable tr:last').after(appendRow);
});

$('#addtable').on('change', '.selector', function () {
  var theVal = $(this).val(),
      tr     = $(this).closest('tr');

  switch (theVal) {
    case '1':
      $('.cutowe, .obtainamount, .obtainroom', tr).prop('disabled', false);
      break;
    case '2':
      $('.cutother', tr).prop('disabled', false);
      break;
    default:
      $('.cutowe, .obtainamount, .obtainroom, .cutother', tr).prop('disabled', true);
      break;
  }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2jyy/8/)

I upgraded the jQuery version, and if you're seriously using jQuery 1.3, so should you.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the `id` to `class`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnAddMore').click(function () {
    $('#addtable tr:last').after($('#addtable tr:last').clone(true));


    $('select.selector').change(function () {
        var theVal = $(this).val();
        switch (theVal) {
            case '1':
               $(this).parents('tr').find('input.cutowe,input.obtainamount,nput.obtainroom').removeAttr('disabled');
                break;
            case '2':
                $(this).parents('tr').find('input.cutowe,input.obtainamount,input.obtainroom,input.cutother').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
        }
    });
 });


});
```

The above code can be reduced to even more, but this should give you a start on knowing few things, like it is a bad idea to have the same ids and how you can access the other columns from current

http://jsfiddle.net/N2jyy/9/

Answer (score 1):

Check this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
        $('#addtable tr:last').after($('#addtable tr:last').clone());
        $('#addtable tr').each(function(){
            var currentTR = $(this);
            $(this).find('select#selector').change(function(){
              var theVal = $(this).val();
          switch(theVal){
            case '1':
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutowe').removeAttr('disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainamount').removeAttr('disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainroom').removeAttr('disabled');
              break;
            case '2':
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutother').removeAttr('disabled');
              break;
            default:
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutowe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainamount').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $(currentTR).find('input#obtainroom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutother').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              break;
             }
            });
        });
    });
    $('#addtable tr').each(function(){
            var currentTR = $(this);
            $(this).find('select#selector').change(function(){
              var theVal = $(this).val();
          switch(theVal){
            case '1':
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutowe').removeAttr('disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainamount').removeAttr('disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainroom').removeAttr('disabled');
              break;
            case '2':
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutother').removeAttr('disabled');
              break;
            default:
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutowe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#obtainamount').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $(currentTR).find('input#obtainroom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $(currentTR).find('input#cutother').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              break;
              }
            });
        });
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2jyy/10/)